# Remove iCloud from app in app store

Tags: iphone, icloud, applications

How do I permanently delete an app from the iCloud in the app store on  my iPhone 7 plus?  I downloaded the app to my ihone but cannot log in to the app. So I deleted it from my home screen and though redownloading it would work. But it doesn't.  I need to get it out of the iCloud so I can download a refreshed version.  How do I permanently delete it from the iCloud?

Comment: Have you contacted the developers? If it will launch but you can't login, it would seem the app itself is working.

Answer (score 1):

The cloud symbol in the App Store only indicates that you already bought the app. Redownloading it gives you the same version as people get which buy it fresh.